# How would I find out that exists only one unique combinations from array of string that gonna fit for a string as keys?

Tags: c#

How would I find out that exists only one unique combinations from array of string that gonna fit for a string as keys?

Let me give you example of prefix code that I'm looking for...
Lets say message is `01001101110` and we have got a keys for this message `0, 10, 11`.

So we can encode it only once time, with these keys, so it is gonna look like =>
`0 10 0 11 0 11 10` so function's code shall `return True`.
However, what if we have message is `01001101110` and we have got a keys for this message `0, 10, 11, 100`.

We gonna be able to encode it twice like this:
`0 10 0 11 0 11 10` and another way to solve it is `0 100 11 0 11 10`
So code gonna return `false`
I see `.Split()` is troublesome as solution when we have only one char to split by the whole string out of there...

Comment: What?...please explain in further detail how you get from the message to the encoded value using the keys. Is this some kind of standard we're just supposed to know, or is it a specific case to your problem? Are we dealing with strings, arrays, etc...  ???

Comment: Just a side note: If any of your keys are a concatenation of any set of your other keys (like the key `100` is a concatenation of keys `10` and `0` in your specific example), and you do find a solution using that "composite" key (`100` in your example), you already know that there will be more than one unique combination.

Comment: We have string of codes like ```string s="01001101110"``` We have also Array of strings like
```string[] as = {"0", "10", "11"}``` We need to figure out how many combinations of ```as``` can fit ```s```
If no combinations or 2 or more combinations are available via ```as``` we return ```false```, ```else``` we ```return true``` since we have 1 only combination fitting for, ```unique one```. ```Split and Replace``` methods are dizzy when we gotta use it for one character length.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a program to get you started. It generates "sequences" based on the `List<String>` that you pass in:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sequence: a,b,c");
    Sequence s = new Sequence(new List<String> { "a", "b", "c",});
    for(int i=1; i<=39; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"#{0}: {1}", s.SequenceNumber, s.CurrentSequence);
        s.Increment();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Sequence: cat,fish,lizard");
    Sequence s2 = new Sequence(new List<String> { "cat", "fish", "lizard", });
    for (int i = 1; i <= 39; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"#{0}: {1}", s2.SequenceNumber, s2.CurrentSequence);
        s2.Increment();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Quit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class Sequence
{

    private int _sequenceNumber = 1;
    private String _sequence;
    private List<int> counters = new List<int>{0};
    private List<String> _values;

    public Sequence(List<String> values)
    {
        _values = values;
        _sequence = values[0];
    }

    public int SequenceNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _sequenceNumber;
        }
    }

    public String CurrentSequence
    {
        get
        {
            return _sequence;
        }
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        _sequenceNumber++;

        for (int i=0; i<counters.Count; i++)
        {
            if (counters[i] < (_values.Count-1))
            {
                counters[i]++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                counters[i] = 0;
                if (i == (counters.Count-1))
                {
                    counters.Add(0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        List<String> seqs = new List<string>();
        foreach (int counter in counters)
        {
            seqs.Insert(0, _values[counter]);
        }
        _sequence = String.Join("", seqs);                
    }            

}
```

Output:

```
Sequence: a,b,c
#1: a
#2: b
#3: c
#4: aa
#5: ab
#6: ac
#7: ba
#8: bb
#9: bc
#10: ca
#11: cb
#12: cc
#13: aaa
#14: aab
#15: aac
#16: aba
#17: abb
#18: abc
#19: aca
#20: acb
#21: acc
#22: baa
#23: bab
#24: bac
#25: bba
#26: bbb
#27: bbc
#28: bca
#29: bcb
#30: bcc
#31: caa
#32: cab
#33: cac
#34: cba
#35: cbb
#36: cbc
#37: cca
#38: ccb
#39: ccc

Sequence: cat,fish,lizard
#1: cat
#2: fish
#3: lizard
#4: catcat
#5: catfish
#6: catlizard
#7: fishcat
#8: fishfish
#9: fishlizard
#10: lizardcat
#11: lizardfish
#12: lizardlizard
#13: catcatcat
#14: catcatfish
#15: catcatlizard
#16: catfishcat
#17: catfishfish
#18: catfishlizard
#19: catlizardcat
#20: catlizardfish
#21: catlizardlizard
#22: fishcatcat
#23: fishcatfish
#24: fishcatlizard
#25: fishfishcat
#26: fishfishfish
#27: fishfishlizard
#28: fishlizardcat
#29: fishlizardfish
#30: fishlizardlizard
#31: lizardcatcat
#32: lizardcatfish
#33: lizardcatlizard
#34: lizardfishcat
#35: lizardfishfish
#36: lizardfishlizard
#37: lizardlizardcat
#38: lizardlizardfish
#39: lizardlizardlizard
Press Enter to Quit.
```

I'll leave it up to you to figure out how many sequences you need to produce for your input, and whether the "target" sequence was produced more than once.